# Qt window is cropped

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I wrote a c++ program using Qt, on my PC, and some test's PC it's work good. But on PC one of the users has cropped window. I attach characteristics of QMainWindow and a photo of cropped window. Please help. What is the problem?

[image: Cropped window]

[image: QMainWindow]

Comment: You should [edit] your question to show your code correctly formatted -- preferably in the form of a [mcve].  Having said that, the first thing I'd recommend is getting rid of the 'fixed' size policies on widgets: just let the layouts do their job.

Comment: I suspect that this user has fractional display scaling such as 125 %, 150% or 175 %, maybe has HighDPI display... and these possible do not play well together if you set fixed window size, as you did. If you are testing your application you should test it also in these above mentioned scenarios. Also note that there were some changes in window size scaling behaviour in Qt during transition from Qt5 to Qt6. What Qt version do you have?

Comment: I have Qt 6.3.1 and scaling doesn't matter.